# TDateTime To ShortDateString In Satellite Forms "VB-clone"

Tags: delphi, tdatetime, satelliteforms

I am trying to find a calculation that will convert the TDateTime value 40653.6830593 into a year, a month, a day, an hour, a minute and a second.

I am sure this is possible, of course, but my brain doesn't have the power, it seems, to write a formula that will extract those values from that double.

I am using a Satellite Forms, a vb-like language, but don't expect that I would need any specific .NET libraries to do this, right?  It should just be a numeric calculation... right?

Thanks for the help!  Most sincerely.

Joe

Comment: For verification, is your intended output for that value equal to 4/20/11 4:23:36 PM?

Comment: Does this "vb-like" language have a name?

Comment: To extract Hours, remember 1.0 = 24 hours, thus hours:= floor(0.6830593*24) mod 24, minutes:= floor(0.6830593*24*60) mod 60, seconds:= minutes:= floor(0.6830593*24*60*60) mod 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legacy VB or VBA (even Excel) would treat a Date as the number of days since 12/30/1899, and I believe the same is true for Delphi. As such, in legacy VB/VBA, you could write

```
Dim myDate as Date
myDate = myDate + 40653.68303593
```

To get April 20, 2011 4:23:36 PM. In VB.NET, it's different, as the DateTime struct defaults to January 1, 0001.

```
Dim myDate As New DateTime(1899, 12, 30)
myDate = myDate.AddDays(40653.68303593)
```

Another user has already posted a Delphi answer.

At any rate, the basic premise is that you're adding the number of days, with the decimal portion representing the time. So in this example, 40653 full days have passed since 12/30/1899, and 0.683... partial days.

Comment: worth to mention what fraction is special

Answer (score 2):

Based on your 'Delphi' tag...

**In Delphi**

```
implementation

uses DateUtils;

....    
var
  MyDate: TDateTime;
  ...other vars...
begin
  MyDate:= double(40653.6830593);
  MyYear:= YearOf(MyDate);
  MyMonth:= MonthOf(MyDate);
  MyDay:= DayOf(MyDate);
  MyHour:= HourOf(MyDate);
  MyMinute:= ... ah well you get the idea.
```

BTW: VB or Delphi, which is it?

**If you want to roll your own**

From the sysutils unit (released under a dual license GPL2/Borland No nonsense)
Which you can find at: http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidF6715D3FD1D4A92BA7F29F96643D8E9D11C1089F.aspx?s=hook

```
function DecodeDateFully(const DateTime: TDateTime; var Year, Month, Day, DOW: Word): Boolean;
const
  D1 = 365;
  D4 = D1 * 4 + 1;
  D100 = D4 * 25 - 1;
  D400 = D100 * 4 + 1;
var
  Y, M, D, I: Word;
  T: Integer;
  DayTable: PDayTable;
begin
  T := DateTimeToTimeStamp(DateTime).Date;
  if T <= 0 then
  begin
    Year := 0;
    Month := 0;
    Day := 0;
    DOW := 0;
    Result := False;
  end else
  begin
    DOW := T mod 7 + 1;
    Dec(T);
    Y := 1;
    while T >= D400 do
    begin
      Dec(T, D400);
      Inc(Y, 400);
    end;
    DivMod(T, D100, I, D);
    if I = 4 then
    begin
      Dec(I);
      Inc(D, D100);
    end;
    Inc(Y, I * 100);
    DivMod(D, D4, I, D);
    Inc(Y, I * 4);
    DivMod(D, D1, I, D);
    if I = 4 then
    begin
      Dec(I);
      Inc(D, D1);
    end;
    Inc(Y, I);
    Result := IsLeapYear(Y);
    DayTable := @MonthDays[Result];
    M := 1;
    while True do
    begin
      I := DayTable^[M];
      if D < I then Break;
      Dec(D, I);
      Inc(M);
    end;
    Year := Y;
    Month := M;
    Day := D + 1;
  end;
end;


function IsLeapYear(Year: Word): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Year mod 4 = 0) and ((Year mod 100 <> 0) or (Year mod 400 = 0));
end;

function TryEncodeDate(Year, Month, Day: Word; out Date: TDateTime): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  DayTable: PDayTable;
begin
  Result := False;
  DayTable := @MonthDays[IsLeapYear(Year)];
  if (Year >= 1) and (Year <= 9999) and (Month >= 1) and (Month <= 12) and
    (Day >= 1) and (Day <= DayTable^[Month]) then
  begin
    for I := 1 to Month - 1 do Inc(Day, DayTable^[I]);
    I := Year - 1;
    Date := I * 365 + I div 4 - I div 100 + I div 400 + Day - DateDelta;
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: -1. I don't see how this is helpful. The question clearly states that the language being used is a "VB-like" language, not Delphi. The Delphi tag is there because the question is *about* the Delphi data type. An answer using Delphi-specific library functions isn't much help for someone using a different language. Maybe you could describe how `DecodeDate` works, instead, since that's what those functions all use. (And the functions are `YearOf`, `MonthOf`, etc., not just `Year`, `Month`, ....)

Comment: @Rob included the code for DecodeDate, EncodeDate and IsLeapYear as well as a link. To bad the OP hasn't listed this mysterious language he's using, 'cause the stuff he's trying to do is probably already done in a standard lib for that language/IDE already.

Comment: It is helpful, translate the above code to whatever "vb like" language you have.  Its extremely unhelpful not to specify the actual language, but that's the OP's problem.

Comment: Wow!  This place is super helpful.. thanks for the replies.  I should have checked back sooner to add more information.  The mystery "VB-like" language I am using is a scripting language bundled with a mobile application RAD tool called Satellite Forms.  The syntax is very vb-like (Len, InStr, Mod, etc...).  I am looking for a way to turn a double into its component year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.  From there, I will be able to generate a shortdatestring.

Answer (score 0):

To extract Hours:

remember 1.0 = 1 day = 24 hours, thus

```
DayPart:= double(MyDateTime) - Floor(double(MyDateTime));    
//there is a function for fraction, but I forgot the name, 
//never use that stuff. 

//if we want to round 0.9999999999 up from 23:59:59 to 24:00:00, do this:
if (RoundTimeUpByHalfASecond = true) then DayPart:= DayPart + (1/(24*60*60*2));

hours:= floor(DayPart*24);
minutes:= floor(DayPart*24*60) mod 60; 
seconds:= minutes:= floor(DayPart*24*60*60) mod 60;
```

Hope that helps